# go-ethereum log.data for event is incomplete and missing

Tags: go-ethereum, events

I have a problem with listening to events, I'm running SubscribeFilterLogs with

```go
query := ethereum.FilterQuery{
        Addresses: []common.Address{contractAddress},
        Topics:    [][]common.Hash{{contractABI.Events["Lock"].ID}},
    }
```

And I get the all events.
The problem occurs with the data field of the Log
it's missing two of the inputs field that are in the emit event
I tested it using js' ethers and there it returns all inputs
The difference is the following:
This is the structure for the response as solidity:

```
event Lock(
        uint16 indexed assetID,
        address indexed token,
        uint256 amount,
        address user,
        uint256 targetChain
    );
```

what the log returns in GO is:
`Lock([<nil> <nil> 1000 0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8 2])`
what the log returns in JS is:

```json
{assetID: "1n",
token: "0x0165878A594ca255338adfa4d48449f69242Eb8F",
amount: "1000n",
user: "0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8",
targetChain: "2n"}
```

I can't understand where the problem occurs,
I even read the bytes for the response in GO and it's empty as it enters from the channel, so it isn't a problem in my parsing